# How many meta questions should have a 'featured' tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, meta

Currently we have two sticky threads. I think it's okay, since both are currently important.

- [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/87)
- [Let's create tag excerpts and wiki entries!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/87)

But in general: How many meta questions should have a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag?

1, 2 ... or maximum 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use with great restraint.** It's pretty rare that you actually have to 'feature' a post. The system already has processes in place to raise certain meta posts to the main Q&A. The [featured](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag was intended to be used for *exceptional* situations only, typically when timely issue comes up that are of *broad* involvement of the entire site.

But be careful about the temptation of slapping a [featured](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag on a post you simply want people to see. Every user feels their meta post is important, and with so many posts vying for attention, the ability for Moderators♦ to say their post is more important than the rest is really easy to abuse.