# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ethereum's [1st moderator election](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: MOD1_NAME] [image: MOD2_NAME] [image: MOD3_NAME]

Both Tjaden Hess and Badr Bellaj will be be replacing [the pro tempore moderators](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) shortly, and eth will be continuing their role - please thank both crews for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5205313523286016).

Comment: Best people for the job - congratulations guys! :-)

Comment: Thank you Richard.

Comment: Congratulations all!

Comment: Congratulations to winners!

Comment: I for one welcome our new Ethereum overlords :) Congratulations to all those involved!

Comment: I vote for Badr and Eth, they are the best for this job ^^

Answer (score 9):

Let me be the first to thank everyone for participating in our first round of elections, and especially congratulations to Badr, Tjaden and eth for accepting this lifetime responsibility to look after Ethereum Stack Exchange!

Feel free to ping me on chat anytime you like if you need any 4th opinion :-)

Comment: Lifetime? :)  Congratulations and welcome Bellaj and Tjaden!  Thanks for offering the chat 5chdn :) and we'll always welcome your suggestions (you might still be among the most active on Meta because it hasn't appeared to be any of us 3 "strengths").

Comment: Yes if you get a diamond from an election, they are assigned to you forever unless you give them back. :p

Answer (score 6):

As we have entered the final phase of a Stack Exchange site (The Full Launch/Graduation Phase) this site has certainly came a long way from the [proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704?phase=definition) on [Area51.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) to what it is today.The [first election](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/1) has came to an end and our moderators have been elected there shall watch over this site,help others in the community and help the ethereum community as well.

[**Congrats Tjaden Hess,Badr Bellaj and eth**]: on *winning the ethereum.SE first moderator election! :)*